# 4x 25% boxes in one line

Tags: html, css

I started learning CSS3 and got a problem, i want to create 4 black boxes(divs), and put them on in one line, 3 of them work properly, but 4th is moving to new line, what am i doing wrong?

My guess would be that its because of the 10px margin, but i dont know how to do it properly.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; }

body {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box; }

#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; }

#block1 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px; }

#block2 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px; }

#block3 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px; }

#block4 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px; }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="block1"></div>
        <div id="block2"></div>
        <div id="block3"></div>
        <div id="block4"></div>
    </div> </body>
```

Comment: try `width: calc(25% - 10px)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body { 
      font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; 
    }
    
    #wrapper {
      width: 1000px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    #block1 {
      width: calc(25% - 10px);
      height: 100px;
      background-color: black;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px; }
    
    #block2 {
      width: calc(25% - 10px);
      height: 100px;
      background-color: black;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px; }
    
    #block3 {
      width: calc(25% - 10px);
      height: 100px;
      background-color: black;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px; }
    
    #block4 {
      width: calc(25% - 10px);
      height: 100px;
      background-color: black;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px; 
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="block1">
    Stuff1
  </div>
  <div id="block2">
    Stuff2
  </div>
  <div id="block3">
    Stuff3
  </div>
  <div id="block4">
    Stuff4
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to substract your margin-right value from your width, otherwise it adds up to more than 100% width.

Try

```
width: calc(25% - 10px);
height: 100px;
background-color: black;
float: left;
margin-right: 10px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try reducing your % by 1%.

```
#block4 {
width: 24%;
height: 100px;
background-color: black;
float: left;
margin-right: 10px; 
}
```